# ¿Como evito que un dato erróneo entre a la base de datos SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Estoy usando C# (WPF) en visual studio 2017 community, y una base de datos SQL (SQL server), y ahora mismo estoy haciendo una interfaz para que el usuario ingrese su nombre y su apellido y este se almacene en mi base de datos.

El problema es que cuando el usuario deja algún campo en blanco(específicamente un `TextBox`), envío un mensaje sobre el campo en blanco con `If` bastante simple, el problema viene que el dato entra en mi base de datos de todas formas, y el campo queda en blanco o falla la primary key de mi Base de Datos.

Quería saber si hay algún método o algún comando que pueda usar para evitar que el campo en blanco entre de todas formas a mi Base de Datos. (estoy conectado a través de entity framwork 6.0)

Comment: Por favor, comparte parte del código con el que tienes problemas para poder saber qué es lo que has intentado.

Comment: Hay muchos métodos para hacer validaciones en Wpf y C# en general. La pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que envias a la bdd directamente los datos de los controles, eso no se debe hacer.

Una opción es crear una clase qie reciba los datos que capturaste y que pueda validarlos.

```
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; }
    public string Apellido { get; }

    public Persona(string nombre, string apellido)
    {
         Nombre = nombre;
         Apellido = apellido;
    }

    public bool EsValido()
    {
         return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nombre) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Apellido);
    }
}
```

De esta forma en vez de usar directamente los datos de los controles, primero los pasas a esta clase, por ejemplo:

```
var persona = new Persona(txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text);
if (persona.EsValido())
{
    // aquí mandas guardar a la bdd, usando las propiedades de la clase persona
}
```

Incluso puedes crear una clase base para reusarla con otras entidades:

```
public abstract class ValidaBase
{
     public abstract bool EsValido();
}
```

Ya puedes heredar de esta clase y te obliga a crear un método EsValido.

Recuerda: No utilizar directamente los datos de los controles.

Answer (score 3):

Primero tienes en C# varias opciones para validar la información que te llega en un objeto de tipo string.

Por ejemplo:

1. Tienes la propiedad `"Length"` que te da la cantidad de caracteres que contiene la cadena.
2. Tienes la función `"Contains("textoABuscar")"` que te indica si la variable contiene algún juego en de caracteres, para tu caso yo validaría con un espacio `"if (myCadena.Contains(" ")) ..."` y con esto te aseguras que no te lleguen espacios en blanco.
3. Ahora bien si quieres algo más avanzado puedes validar los textos que te llegan con un patrón de comparación como este `@"^\w{4,7}$"` usando `Regex`.

así:

```
 public void testRegex(string textToValidate)
 { 
     string = pattern = @"^\w{2,15}$"; 
     Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); 

     if (!rgx.IsMatch(textToValidate))
     { 
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Error en la entrada {0}", textToValidate)); 
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Correcto la entrada {0}", textToValidate)); 
     } 
 }
```

De esa forma te aseguras que no te metan espacios en blanco (Cualquier cantidad) y con los números `{l,m}` puedes definir cuántos caracteres aceptas cómo mínimo `(l)` y cuántos como máximo `(m)`.

Modificando esa función puedes validar si la cadena que introdujeron cumple con tus requerimientos y en caso contrario, pues devuleves un mensaje al usuario para que corrija el campo en específico.

Espero te sirva, saludos!!